# Why include quadratic terms in interactions in lmer?

Tags: r, mixed-model, interaction, lme4-nlme, quadratic-form

Can someone please clarify whether I need to include a quadratic term in interactions instead of just using the linear term?

I have a mixed model with a logarithmized response variable and three predictors. One of the predictors (=time) has a curved relationship with the response. I also have two important interactions of time with the other two predictors that I need to include (both factors= temperature and precipitation).
My model is:
`poly.model <- lmer(logng ~ poly(time, 2) * temp + poly(time, 2) * precip +  (1|indiv))`

Results:

> ```
> Estimate Std. Error        df t value Pr(>|t|)    
> (Intercept)              3.60072    0.14030  17.70000  25.665 1.78e-15 ***
> poly(time, 2)1          -5.30865    0.91882 345.00000  -5.778 1.69e-08 ***
> poly(time, 2)2          -1.53108    0.91882 345.00000  -1.666  0.09655 .  
> tempW                    0.03442    0.05592 345.00000   0.616  0.53859    
> precipW                 -0.04454    0.05592 345.00000  -0.796  0.42630    
> poly(time, 2)1:tempW     3.31625    1.06096 345.00000   3.126  0.00192 ** 
> poly(time, 2)2:tempW    -1.22307    1.06096 345.00000  -1.153  0.24979    
> poly(time, 2)1:precipW   5.26588    1.06096 345.00000   4.963 1.09e-06 ***
> poly(time, 2)2:precipW  -1.47913    1.06096 345.00000  -1.394  0.16417
> ```

The interactions with quadratic terms are not significant and if I plot[image: plot] the effect of `poly(time, 2) * temp` the SEs overlap at each value of time and thus it appears there is no difference.

Can someone please help me understand why I need to include the quadratic time interactions despite those interactions are not significant? The interactions that include linear time are highly significant. However, if I construct:

`alt.model <- lmer(logng ~ time + I(time^2) + temp + precip + time:precip + time:temp + (1|indiv))`
and then plot the effects of `time:temp`, the resulting plot is identical to the one above. Again, it appears that the interaction is not significant, but yes according to the output:

Results:

> ```
> Estimate Std. Error        df t value Pr(>|t|)    
> (Intercept)    3.60574    0.20587  63.10000  17.515  < 2e-16 ***
> time           0.26245    0.08456 339.00000   3.104  0.00207 ** 
> I(time^2)     -0.06090    0.01136 339.00000  -5.360 1.54e-07 ***
> tempW         -0.32378    0.12924 339.00000  -2.505  0.01271 *  
> precipW       -0.61332    0.12924 339.00000  -4.745 3.07e-06 ***
> time:precipW   0.16251    0.03319 339.00000   4.897 1.51e-06 ***
> time:tempW     0.10234    0.03319 339.00000   3.084  0.00221 **
> ```

Thank you very much for the clarification of whether I need the quadratic terms in interactions and why is my plot suggesting no difference.

Comment: You should at least add the raw data to the plot.

Comment: @Roland I prefer no to post the data publicly, sorry. Is it possible to answer these questions generally without the data please-- that is whether one needs to include quadratic terms in interactions instead of just using the linear terms and how come a significant interaction term appears non-significant when visualized. Thanks so much